# Express React app works locally but gives error on heroku deploy

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

i'm sure this has been solved, but i am unable to get this to work for me.

locally my repo works with this as my

/index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const keys = require("./config/keys");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// uses fuzeRoutes
require("./routes/routes")(app);

app.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname, "public", "index.html");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, function() {
  console.log(
    "Express server listening on port %d in %s mode",
    this.address().port,
    app.settings.env
  );
});
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  }
```

now this works locally with no issue but on heroku deploy i get an error 
`at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/"`

looking through other questions i see its due to `"SSL termination occurs at Heroku's load balancers; they send your app plain (non-SSL) traffic, so your app should create a non-HTTPS server."` looking through the other questions asked, i am either not understanding the resolution, or i am not finding the correct thread.

any help would be appreciated

**UPDATE:**

I was able to resolve the issue with the H13 error.

The issue was :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
//
//
//
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname, "public", "index.html");
});
```

should have been :

```
   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/public")));
    //
    //
    //
    app.get("*", function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname,"client", "public", "index.html");
    });
```

The issue is now when deployed I get a 200 status code with `at=info method=GET path="/"` but the page returns blank. the HTML of the page shows it has a the `<div id="root">` in the build path, but the page does not load the react components.

Comment: Do you have a [`Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)?

Comment: @zsgomori i do not have have one in this project no

Answer (score 0):

I've deployed the following express configuration to Heroku to a create-react-app application:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/public')))

app.get('*', function(_, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/public/index.html'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
})
```

You can see the full [code here](https://github.com/agencyenterprise/aeboilerplate/blob/master/server/index.ts).

Comment: Thanks! that resolved he issue changing the function.