# React content not found heroku deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, create-react-app

Im trying to deploy a nodejs and react app to Heroku. It works completely fine local and it does serve my backend, but i get Not Found on anything else than my api endpoints. It seems like its not running the build script in the client folder. Can anyone help me spot where it goes wrong?

> server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const projects = require('./routes/api/projects');

const app = express();

// Body parser middlewaree
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB Config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

// Connect to DB
mongoose
.connect(
 db,
 { useNewUrlParser: true }
)
.then(() => console.log('mongoDB connected.'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

// Setting up routes
app.use('/api/projects', projects);

// Serve static assets if in production
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendfile(path.join((__dirname, '/client/build/index.html')));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server up and running on ${port}`));
```

> package.json

```
"scripts": {
"client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
"start": "node server.js",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"client": "npm start --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
},
```

Comment: Could you please post the full server.js code?

Comment: Sorry, its updated

Answer (score 0):

I've deployed successfully to Heroku using the following code (I've just answered an alike question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357546/express-react-app-works-locally-but-gives-error-on-heroku-deploy/54379421#54379421)):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')))

app.get('*', function(_, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
})
```

Also, if you're trying to deploy a create-react-app application, you can use [this buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git). Buildpacks are scripts that are run when your app is deployed. They are used to install dependencies for your app and configure your environment.

You can see the [full code here](https://github.com/agencyenterprise/aeboilerplate/blob/master/server/index.ts) of how I usually deploy Heroku applications.